# OWL Carousel move + / - 5 slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I would like to be able to move OWL Carousel + /- 5 slides depending on what current slide it's on. Please see my demo below, you can see I accomplish this by using `carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 5)` then `carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 1)` to go back.
But once I'm on 5 I would like to to go +5 slides again, the same with back. It currently only stays on the slide.

[Code Pen Demo](http://codepen.io/Marcus_Dev/pen/xZRaWe)

Here is my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var carousel = $("#owl-demo");

carousel.owlCarousel({
  slideSpeed : 500,
  navigation: false
});

$('.goTo').click(function(){
carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 5)
});

$('.goToback').click(function(){
carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 1)
});

$('.jumpTo').click(function(){
carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 10)
});

$('.jumpToBack').click(function(){
carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 1)
});


});
```

Please let me know if I need to clear anything up

Here is the website [OWL Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the current slide and goTo [currentItem](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/owlStatus.html) + 5 (or -5)

https://jsfiddle.net/ubLLx7q9/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var owl = null;
    var carousel = $("#owl-demo");

    carousel.owlCarousel({
      slideSpeed : 500,
      navigation: false,
      afterInit: function () {
        owl = this;
      }
    });

  $('.goTo').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', owl.currentItem + 5)
  });

  $('.goToback').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', owl.currentItem - 5)
  });
});
```